# R markdown ! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. error occured

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

In R markdown I want to make the table with 2 rows and 8 columns.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
variable & N & Mean & Std.Dev & SE Mean & 95% cI & T & P \\
Y & 25 & 92.5805 & ? & 0.4673 & (91.6160, ?) & ? & 0.002 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I entered this command and it returns this error message.

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate 

l.101 Y & 25 & 92.5805 &

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

I guess I entered tabular right and nothing to be calculated.

They' are just texts and numbers.

I tried to search similar questions and compare the examples codes.

But I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify your tablar correctly with extra vertical bars `|` at the beginning and at the end. In addition escape the percent sign with a backslash `\%`, otherwise it has a meaning as a program code.

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
 \hline
 variable & N & Mean & Std.Dev & SE Mean & 95\% cI & T & P \\
 Y & 25 & 92.5805 & ? & 0.4673 & (91.6160, ?) & ? & 0.002 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Hope this would work for you?

Comment: Also for others encountering this issue, "&" will also throw and error if you are using kableExtra. I just used "+" instead, but you can also use "\\&" to escape the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when omitting a justification argument for one of the aligned columns. In this example, I want to left justify two equations using an `array` rather than a `table`:

```
\begin{array}{l}
\hat{z} =& \frac{\beta_0}{1 - \beta_z} \\
\hat{z}' =& \beta_0+\beta_z\left(\frac{\beta_0}{1-\beta_z}\right).
\end{array}
```

For which we see the same error:

```
! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.
<recently read> \endtemplate
```

Indeed the principle of the issue is the same as for `\tabular`, however adding vertical bars `|` will not fix the problem. Only by adding the missing `l` in `\begin{array}{l}` (which becomes `\begin{array}{ll}`) resolved the error.